# How to read column value using grails excel import plugin?

Tags: grails, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using Grails excel import plugin to import an excel file.

```
      static Map propertyConfigurationMap = [
          name:([expectedType: ExcelImportService.PROPERTY_TYPE_STRING, defaultValue:null]),
          age:([expectedType: ExcelImportService.PROPERTY_TYPE_INT, defaultValue:0])]

      static Map CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP = [
          sheet:'Sheet1',
          startRow: 1,
          columnMap:  [
           //Col, Map-Key
           'A':'name',
           'B':'age',
          ]
         ]
```

I am able to retrieve the array list by using the code snippet:

def usersList = excelImportService.columns(workbook, CONFIG_USER_COLUMN_MAP)

which results in

[[name: Mark, age: 25], [name: Jhon, age: 46], [name: Anil, age: 62], [name: Steve, age: 32]]

And also I'm able to read each record say [name: Mark, age: 25] by using usersList.get(0)

How do I read the each column value?
I know I can read something like this

```
String[] row = usersList.get(0)
for (String s : row)
    println s
```

I wonder is there any thing that plugin supports so that I can read column value directly rather manipulating it to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `usersList` is basically a `List<Map<String, Object>>` (list of maps). You can read a column using the name you gave it in the config. In your example, you named column A *name* and column B *age*. So using your iteration example as a basis, you can read each column like this:

```
Map row = usersList.get(0)

for(Map.Entry entry : row) {
    println entry.value
}
```

Groovy makes this easier to do with `Object.each(Closure)`:

```
row.each { key, value -> 
    println value 
}
```

If you want to read a specific column value, here are a few ways to do it:

```
println row.name // One
println row['name'] // Two
println row.getAt('name') // Three
```

Hint: These all end up calling `row.getAt('name')`